# Get more than 200 events from the Meetup API v3 using OAuth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, meetup

Fetching more than 200 entries of Events was possible in the meetup API v2 and earlier using the PAGE and OFFSET params.
Using the meetup API v3 (the only way since 2019-08-15) you can only add the PAGE param, OFFSET doesn't work/is not available and PAGE returns 200 entries max.
Does anyone have an idea how to fetch e.g. 600 entries from 5 years back?

This is the current doc for v3:
https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/console/?path=/:urlname/events

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the returned `Link` headers for one with a `rel="next"` attribute, as (briefly) [documented here](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/#v3_json).

Comment: Well, looking at the header always gives me a "…scroll=since%3A2015-01-18T20%3A00%3A00.000%2B01%3A00…" (or "scroll=since:2015-01-18T20:00:00.000+01:00") back.
This I can not change (afaik)! And send a "scroll" in the request I'm allowed to send "future_or_past"  and a "no_earlier_than" or "no_later_than" with a date. But that's a different scope! I can chunks of events base don a timeframe but not based on the order they exist (as page and offset does).

What am I doing wrong here?